# JavaScript Implementation of VIM

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm looking for variants of Vi implemented in Javascript.

Unfortunately, I've been getting all types of results of configuring Vim for writing JavaScript code.

The only helpful result I've found is JSVI.

Question: are there any other (perhaps more modern) impelmentations I should look into?

Comment: There are many and they are all crap. Why don't you ask on Google? You'll get more results faster than asking random strangers to search google for you.

Comment: Why exactly do you want a jsc vim?

Comment: @romaini, because Googling usually points to StackOverflow anyway and it can be difficult to know from Google searches which implementations are good, like vim.js from x_vi_r's answer (even though I had trouble finding this via Google).

Answer (score 11):

You should have a look to Vim.js  a full Vim written in Javascript, works in your browser

1. Persistent ~/.vimrc
2. Execute JavaScript from Vim.js
3. Read local files
4. Read files from Dropbox

Have fun !

http://coolwanglu.github.io/vim.js/web/vim.html

If you want something faster there is a VI implementation made by some MIT student here: 
http://web.mit.edu/~georgiou/www/vi/

Comment: +1 This looks awesome, definitely should be up-voted more.

Comment: Looks good, but it's too slow.

Comment: The new version here starts really quickly once the data is cached.  http://coolwanglu.github.io/vim.js/emterpreter/vim.html  The new "emterpreter" version uses 1.6MB first time, while the old "streamlinejs" version uses 2.3MB first time.  Both use about 16KB when the data already cached.  For my computer, old version takes about 6 seconds to start when cached, new version takes only about 1 second to start.

Answer (score 7):

The [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org) editor has vim keybindings bindings as well as keybindings from other popular editors, however this is not a complete implementation of vim.

The source for ACE can be found on [GitHub](http://github.com/ajaxorg/ace).

Comment: Pretty looking, but doesn't even support / to search for text - the primary way of navigating in VIM (for me, anyway).  Still, might be worth-while base, one can always add the feature subset that suits. HJKL navigation worked at least.

Answer (score 4):

Try [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/demo/vim.html). It emulates VIM pretty faithfully, and supports:

1. Most common motions and operators in normal mode
2. Operator/motion orthogonality
3. Visual mode
4. Registers
5. Marks
6. Search & Replace `/`, `*`, `g*`, `:substitute`
7. Macros
8. Text objects

Still, this is in no way a complete VIM implementation in Javascript, it just tries to emulate the most useful features as faithfully as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing vi clone in javascript called wasavi for Chrome/Opera/Firefox extension.
Although wasavi is not perfect yet, supports almost all the vi/ex commands.

If you are interested, please try: http://appsweets.net/wasavi/

and source code is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi).

Answer (score 1):

Check [vim-in-textarea](https://github.com/jakub-m/vim-in-textarea), together with online demo. It works with HTML textareas and does *not* alter style or look.

Answer (score 0):

Vimulator looks interesting, although is rather limited and is for teaching vim (and has a rather annoying delay built-in):
https://github.com/thoughtbot/vimulator

It was missing the undo command and Shift-% command (for matching brackets). It at least had search function.

There are at least two answers that are a better answer than this one:
http://coolwanglu.github.io/vim.js/web/vim.html 
and
http://codemirror.com.